# How to get last row in each group in code igniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
$this->db->select("tb_salary.* ,tb_unit.name as unit_name,tb_session.name as session_name")       
    ->from('tb_salary as tb_salary')
    ->join("tb_unit as tb_unit","tb_unit.id=tb_salary.unit_id")
    ->join("tb_session as tb_session","tb_session.id=tb_salary.session_id")
    ->where('tb_salary.isDeleted',0)
    ->where('tb_salary.user_id',$id)
    ->order_by("tb_salary.id ","desc")
    ->group_by('tb_salary.name ');


$q=$this->db->get();

return $q->result();
```

Comment: I want to group by with name. I have a three tables tb_unit,tb_session, and tb_salary.

Comment: explain db schema or db fiddle may help you to get faster replies